# XML styles not applied when running android app

Tags: android, xml

So my previewer in Android studio is showing me that styles are being held

(I would post an image but I do not have the reputation)

However, when I run the app the styles disappear, but only the ones specified in styles.xml

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:theme="@style/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcome_text"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="125dp">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/option_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#eee</item>
</style>
<style name="header">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff43a2ff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">60dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerInParent">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use
`style="@style/header"`

instead of
`android:theme="@style/header"`

Check the [Official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) which states

> There are two ways to set a style:
>
> 1. To an individual View, by adding the `style` attribute to a View element in the XML for your layout.
> 2. Or, to an entire Activity or application, by adding the `android:theme` attribute to the  or  element in the Android manifest.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly! The most confusing part was wondering why the preview was displaying what I wanted....